# print entire directory of text files to printer with filename as header using bash or openoffice basic script

Tags: scripting, insert, printing, filenames

I want to print an entire directory of text files to a printer inserting the file name at the top of the first page of each file that is printed. A bash or openoffice script would serve me well. Thanks

Comment: Which operating system are you using (i am guessing a *nix system). Is your printer driver setup to use command line printing ? would lp work against your printer ?

Comment: I am using openSuSE 10. Yes my printer, an HP 4200 will print on commands 'lp' and 'lpr -P HP4200 <filename>  issued from the bash terminal.  Incidentally, I have the KDE Desktop installed and if I could use the included editor 'Kate' which automatically instructs the printer to print the filename in the header, I could avoid the problem of the filename. The trouble is I cannot get Kate to print in batch mode. I guess bash would do what I want, but I am at a loss as to how to write a bash script. Thanks. Ned.

Answer (score 1):

GNU a2ps is nice for this (provides options for multiple pages per sheet, etc.) It can even syntax-highlight source code if you want.

http://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/

Comment: I will have a look at a2ps. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: a2ps led me to enscript which does the job with this line:
enscript -DDuplex:true -X ascii -PHP4200 *
Thanks, Ned.